# How do I seed UAN with AADHAR after three years of work gap

Tags: india, epf

I was working with a company. Then I took three years of education gap. Now I have joined new company. When I tried to login EPFO portal, I was not able to login. The portal says "Aadhar is not available against UAN, Kindly seed aadhaar through employer".

[image]

r/IndiaInvestments - How do I seed UAN with AADHAR after three years of work gap
My new employer is saying seeding needs to be done by earlier employer. I mailed my earlier employer couple of times, but they did not reply.

Now I raised grievance on EPF portal and got following reply after almost a month:

> It is advised to submit the joint declaration duly attested by employer along with all the supportive documents to previous employer and then to present employer to link the aadhaar to UAN.

Please guide me how can fix this?